# Why does my div keep transitioning from bottom to top and not from center?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, transition

I use React and Tailwind and I'm currently experiencing an issue with transition property. I'm trying to achieve the effect of div growing from the center and expanding its width and height until it covers the entire viewport after a certain state variable value becomes true. The div itself should remain where it is (it has another div with content inside of it) and simply grow in width and height.

The issue is that no matter what kind of transition I try (scale, transitioning y and x or even simply transitioning max height of the div) my transition keeps expanding the div from bottom to top of viewport.

This is the snippet of my code:

```
 <div
   className={`z-10 px-8 pb-6 pt-10 text-white transition-all duration-500 ${slideTransition ? "translate-y-[50%]": "translate-y-0"} 
${isFullscreen ? "absolute inset-0 transition-all transform origin-center duration-[1s] ease-in-out": "relative"}
${fullscreenTransition ? 'max-h-screen' : 'max-h-full'}`}
>
```

This is how I trigger the `fullscreenTransition` state change:

```
 const triggerFullscreenTransition = () => {
    if (isFullscreen) return true
    else return false
  }
```

The state change seems to be working alright, the transition does get applied but it instead of growing from center the div simply slides upwards. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can't tell much of anything because those are all class names. Need to see actual styles

Comment: but you need the `transform-origin: center` style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `translateY` which moves the element vertically, what you want to do is to `transition` the `height` and `width`, here's a demo in vanilla javascript and CSS, use full screen to see the full effect:

```js
let red=document.querySelector('.red');
let green=document.querySelector('.green');

function transtaleY(){
  red.classList.toggle('translateY');
}
function HW(){
  green.classList.toggle('transitionHW');
  red.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  width:auto;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
  transition:transform 500ms;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
  transition:height 500ms,width 500ms;
}
.translateY{
  transform:translateY(-100%);
}
.transitionHW{
  height:100vh;/*the new wanted height*/
  width:100vw;/*the new wanted width*/
  transition:height 500ms,width 500ms;
 
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box red">
  <button id="y" onclick='transtaleY()' >translate Y</button>
</div>
<div class="box green">
  <button id="HW" onclick='HW()' >transition height & Width</button>
</div>
```

all you need to do is write the equivalent tailwind utility classes, which I'm not an expert on.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think my issue lies in the fact that I apply position absolute and inset 0 at the same time as I try to transition width and height to expand the div and that disables it from growing from the center. I'm going to investigate this issue further but your response set me in the right track so I'll mark it as accepted.